# How to move shape's stroke gradient with mouse

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

In PS Cs6, there is option to give stroke gradient and it can be aligned with layer however i can't find a way to move it any other way.

I want to, let's say drag gradient.

Answer (score 1):

With the Layer Styles dialog open.. click drag on the document.

[image]

Comment: nice animation :D...but i was talking about vector shape's stroke.

Comment: No, you can't drag the stroke on a Vector layer.